# How to achieve anime style action lines in cycles?

Tags: compositing-nodes, freestyle

I'm trying to achieve an effect similar to this which I found in a tutorial on how to make anime action lines, but unfortunately it was in blender render and I couldn't figure out how to replicate the effects in cycles:

[image]

This is basically what I was able to achieve using compositing, freestyle, and the displacement modifier on a cone staring head on:

[image]
This is what it looks like with the empty affecting the cone with the displacement modifier:

[image]

Here are the material nodes:

[image]

As you can see from my version, it doesn't have a genuine action look to it...is it possible to achieve this with my current setup?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: You mention Cycles in the title but proceed to tag compositor and freestyle. How are you really looking to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure what the discrepancy is...I'm using the compositor and freestyle lines in cycles.  The tutorial I was watching on youtube was in internal and used a lot of nodes that aren't available in cycles.

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by "genuine action look"? Do you want to get darker streaks like in the first example? The bright spot in the center? Or..? Perhaps an animated example of what you are going for would help

Comment: @gandalf3 Yes I'm basically going for the look of the first image...I want to have thicker, more comic book style lines with a bright centre.  But I do want to have a glow effect like the .GIF I posted of my version if that's possible...

Comment: @lakerice I had a go at making this effect with just material nodes, but I don't have time to polish up an answer atm. [Here's the file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4647/) anyway, is that something closer to what you're looking for?

Comment: @gandalf3   Yes that's exactly what I was going for!  Thanks!  I'm studying your node setup...what's the basic workflow/principles?  If you have to time I'd love to understand them.